# How to update array of object in robomongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update "pharmacy_note" field that has inside of array object
my MongoDB collection here

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587f477c890202980f693cd7"),
    "doc_id" : "cf05effe-49ff-4dfc-b286-74469956be6f",
    "visit_id" : "56d29f560a0acbef475d9810",
    "pharmacy_name" : "Hospital Pharmacy",
    "pharmacy_id" : "AB1234",
    "prescription_items" : [ 
        {
            "quantity" : 4,
            "number_of_days" : 2,
            "reg_price" : 1600,
            "reason" : "bacterial infections",
            "instruction" : "Take medicine at the same time each day",
            "route" : "Oral",
            "frequency" : "One Time a day",
            "unit" : "mg",
            "dose" : "250",
            "name" : "Cipro",
            "pharmacy_note" : "this field i want to update",
            "_id" : ObjectId("587f462a890202980f693be4"),
            "is_dispensed" : false,
            "start_date" : ISODate("2017-01-25T18:30:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "prescription_generated" : false,
    "prescribed_date" : ISODate("2017-01-18T10:46:20.885Z"),
    "prescription_id" : "01348416-d38c-4340-b18d-6b7578ef05e5",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: why are you marked my question duplicate if that is duplicate then please provide me solution of this question

Comment: The answer is in the marked duplicate and please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)